# Querying MongoDB (via pymongo) in case insensitive efficiently

Tags: python, mongodb, case-insensitive, pymongo

I'm currently creating a website in python (pyramid) which requires users to sign up and log in.  The system allows for users to choose a username which can be a mixture of capital letters, lowercase letters, and numbers.

The problem arises when making sure that two users don't accidentally share the same username, i.e. in my system 'randomUser' should be the same as 'RandomUser' or 'randomuser'.

Unfortunately (in this case) because Mongo stores strings as case sensitive, there could potentially be a number of users with the 'same' username.

I am aware of the method of querying mongo for case insensitive strings:

```
db.stuff.find_one({"foo": /bar/i});
```

However, this does not seem to work in my query method using pymongo:

```
username = '/' + str(username) + '/i'
response = request.db['user'].find_one({"username":username},{"username":1})
```

Is this the correct way of structuring the query for pymongo (I'm assuming not)?

This query will be used whenever a user account is created or logged in to (as it has to check if the username exists in the system).  I know it's not the most efficient query, so should it matter if it's only used on log ins or account creation?  Is it more desirable to instead do something like forcing users to choose only lowercase usernames (negating the need for case-insensitive queries altogether)?

Comment: Keep in mind that this requires a full table scan - indexes cannot be used with regular expressions unless they are case insensitive and the regex is relative to "beginning of line, `^`".

Comment: I think you mean "unless they are case sensitive"

Answer (score 58, accepted):

PyMongo uses native python regular expressions, in the same way as the mongo shell uses native javascript regular expressions. To write the equivalent query of what you had written in the shell above, you would use:

```
db.stuff.find_one({'name': re.compile(username, re.IGNORECASE)})
```

Note that this will avoid using any index that may exist on the `name` field, however. A common pattern for case-insensitive searching or sorting is to have a second field in your document, for instance `name_lower`, which is always set whenever `name` changes (to a lower-cased version of `name`, in this case). You would then query for such a document like:

```
db.stuff.find_one({'name_lower': username.lower()})
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing that up for me.  I will use the name_lower method (it had been mentioned in other places as well)

Comment: Wouldn't that be a problem if the "username" variable contains regular expression metacharacters?

Comment: A safer query would be: `db.stuff.find_one({'name': re.compile('^' + re.escape(username) + '$', re.IGNORECASE)})`

Answer (score 11):

Accepted answer is dangerous, it will match any string containing the username! Safe option is to match the exact string:

```
import re
db.stuff.find_one({'name': re.compile('^' + username + '$', re.IGNORECASE)})
```

Even safer, escape the variable of any special characters which might affect the regex match:

```
import re
db.stuff.find_one({'name': re.compile('^' + re.escape(username) + '$', re.IGNORECASE)})
```

Comment: Why not to use db.stuff.find_one({'name': username.lower()}) ?

Comment: `username.lower()` would work if all name values in db are lowercase and `username` variable has varying capitalization. Regex is needed if db values are of varying case

Comment: why is it not safe ? find one matches the exact string not substrings

Comment: the regex in the example matches also with a substring

Comment: I just tested the topmost example and it seems to do what it is supposed to. It does not match substrings.

Answer (score 1):

##### Case sensitive:

```
db.stuff.find_one({'name': {'$regex': f'^{username}$'}})
```

##### Case insensitive:

```
db.stuff.find_one({'name': {'$regex': f'^{username}$', "$options": 'i'}})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).