# How to pass exact match word using pymongo to mongodb query?

Tags: python, mongodb, full-text-search, pymongo

I am trying to pass the string for 'exact match' as per the documentation provided on mongodb's website.

**See:** https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases)

They describe the token pattern as `"\"word\""`, but I am unable to pass this with python because the '\' is getting escaped...  How to fix?

**None of these seem to work:**

```py
>>> x='\'word\''
>>> x
"'word'"

>>> x='\"word\"'
>>> x
'"word"'

>>> x='\\"word\\"'
>>> x
'\\"word\\"'

>>> x=r'\"word\"
>>> x
'\\"word\\"'

>>> x=r"\"word\""
'\\"word\\"'

#mongo query
query=mycol.find({"$match": {"$text": { "$search": x }}).limit(10)
return json.loads(dumps(query))
```

I expect search string x to be passed to query as `"\"word\""`.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've investigated this further and I just don't think PyMongo supports this format for exact-search.  I could not find any examples in [PyMongo's documents](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/doc/tutorial.rst) or other documents online.  However, I did find the documentation for *exact-search* on [MongoDb's site](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/).

I think the confusion is that, MongoDb *does* support `"\"word\""`, but [PyMongo's collection.find()](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/collection.py) *does not* seem to.  Every example, I could find, of PyMonogo's find() method was using the standard format of `"word"`.

PyMongo's find() method works by creating a [PyMongo cursor](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/cursor.py).  I don't believe that the construction of this cursor supports the format of "\"word\"".  I suspect this is why `x` can equal `"\"word\""` before it's passes into find(), but returns as `"\\"word\\""` after a query.  I further suspect that find() is already looking for exact-matches and this is why the extra `\`s are added.
**Test Code:**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json

client = MongoClient()
db = client.test_database
mycol = db.test_collection

x = r""""\"word\""""
x += r"""" """
x[:-1]

print(x)
myquery = mycol.find({"$match": {"$text": { "$search": f'{x}' }}}).limit(10)
print(myquery)
```

Please let me know if you've found a solution to this.

Comment: Hi Mathew, Thanks for the response.
I am afraid the string x still parses to '"\\"word\\"" ' in query. But the print statement evals correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me to find an exact match on my MongoDB 3.4 instance:

```
coll.find({"$text":{"$search":'\"exact phrase\"'}})
```

It matches "exact phrase", but does not match "exact other phrase". However, it will also match "exact phrases" because there does not appear to be a word boundary character "\b" like in regular expressions.

This will only work if you have your [$text index set up properly](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/)

You might find that a better solution is [using regular expression in pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6269152/7644323).